JMeter 5.5 distributed testing rconfigure() method error
I am using JMeter version of 5.5 and Java version 11 of Azul and while triggering test in the slave machine getting below error
ERROR o.a.j.e.ClientJMeterEngine: Error in rconfigure() method
java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 10.55.213.68; nested exception is: 
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:623) ~[?:?]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:209) ~[?:?]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:196) ~[?:?]
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:132) ~[?:?]
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:217) ~[?:?]

Tried with different versions of JMeter and java. how to solve the issue?

It indicates either that your RMI configuration is not correct or that ports you've specified there are not open in your operating system firewall
You need to open:

Port 1099 (or whatever is the value of server_port on slaves
Ports specified via client.rmi.localport property on master

More information: How to Perform Distributed Testing in JMeter
Also be aware that according to JMeter Best Practices you should always be using the latest version of JMeter so consider upgrading.
